# Error while instaling Drupal

Tags: 7, database

Please help about below error. I don't know how to resolve below error. I will try several ways follows from searches and drupal.org forums. But error still comes back.

Please check the below image everything I mentioned in that. wamp versions, windows versions.

[image]

Comment: first thing is restart your wamp server, i can see from your image that the wamp icon is yellow, wamp is fully functional when it is green. second is increase your execution time and memory limit from php.ini file.